# runOnUiThread crash when calling in asyntask

Tags: android

im using runOnUiThread to show UI fromasyntask but my app is crash please help me what do i do? how do i showmy Ui on postexecute directly??? im so confuse  why runOnUiThread is crash???? how do i show my textview values on screen??

```
       public class fifthscreen extends Activity {
String num = null;
// TextView ingredient;

// TextView ingredient;

View row4;
int IOConnect = 0;
View row3;

String status;

HorizontalListView listview;
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
String DescriptionAPI;

TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
ImageView img1;
String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String allergen2;
    TableLayout table;
String name;
    LinearLayout table3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);
            table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);
           table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);
}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();

}

public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        parseJSONData();
    }
}

public void parseJSONData() {

    SelectMenuAPI = Utils.dishdescription;

    URL = SelectMenuAPI;
    URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream), 8192);

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

    //final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

        for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

            String s = String.valueOf(j + 1);

            row3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
            ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(school3
                    .getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))

       .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));

            //fifthscreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                //public void run() {
                    table.addView(row3);
                //}
            //});

        }

    //final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);

        JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

        for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

            row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
            ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
            ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                    .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "sub_ingredients"));

            // table3.addView(row2);

            //fifthscreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //  public void run() {
                    table3.addView(row4);
                //}
            //});

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  }
```

Comment: is not crash on simulator is crash on real device see my code and tel me how do i show this textviews ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
            ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                    .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "sub_ingredients")); in post execute??? without using runonUithread????

Comment: You code is totally messy and dirty. I recommend you to completely delete it and try it in different way. Why you added runOnUiThread to background Thread. It makes no sence for me. You shouldn't mix it.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167875/runonuithread-not-work-inside-asyntask-app-crash?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in your below code.

> ```
>   fifthscreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 table3.addView(row4);
>             }
>         });
> ```

You can not update your UI on thread so just remove the runOnUiThread to upate your UI and directly add the view.

Comment: please edit my main code which i post above tel me what u say? my full activity code is above

Comment: @smartguy you are asking others do your work. you need to edit your code based on the suggestion given. Why would you ask anyone to edit your code. go through the suggestions and make necessary changes yourself

Comment: Please check out your code and let me know if there is issue still.

Answer (score 0):

runUIthread itself is a thread , i don't think you can run another thread that is AsyncTask in same.
You can not update your UI in doInBackground

Comment: i don't think that is a problem

Comment: so im calling parseJSONData() on background but inside parseJSONData() i m using textview  how do i move textview part on Postexecute???

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground you have `parseJSONData()`

In `parseJSONData()` you have the below

```
 ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))

   .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));
```

You are updating UI in `doInBackground()`. You are probably getting an exception. You cannot update UI from background Thread that is not synchronized with UI Thread.

You have declared `textview` as a class member. So initialize in `onCreate`. Your asynctask is an inner class of your activity class.

So return the json object in `doInbackground`. The result of `doInbackground` computation is a param to `onPostExecute`. So based on the result update your textview's in `onPostExecute`

You need to initialize these `txt1, txt2, txt3`. Also i see you are inflating a new layout in `parseJSONData()`. I am not sure why. You can initialize your textviews in `onCreate` You can update `txt1, txt2, txt3` in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

```
you are Accessing UI Element into you are do in background...remove it..
1) 
you can return the values from you method public JSonObject parseJSonData()..
2)
now change the AsynTask<Void,Void,String>
public String doInBackGround(Void..arg){}
public onPostExecute(String...arg)

{
//use the TextField here to print the data
}

Try it..this could help...
```

Comment: please tell me programically im not getting how to doprogramiclaly? u mean cutpaste this line from parsejson() to poseexecute?

((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
       .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
         "sub_ingredients"));

Comment: yes,return your string to doInBackGround make the method changes as i have wrote above & its done

Answer (score 0):

when You using an `AsyncTask` you can't invoke UI activity within `doInBackground()`.

I prefer you to use `onPostExecute()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  update GUI here
            }
        }, 50); // dummy delay

    }
```

BTW, AsyncTask has `onProgressUpdate`. You can use it as callback:

```
 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) { /***/}
```

**[EDIT]**

BTW, add something like: `table.removeAllViews();` before you add new View

```
public class fifthscreen extends Activity {
    String num = null;
    // TextView ingredient;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;
    // TextView ingredient;
    long Menu_ID;
    String dish_name;
    View row4;
    int IOConnect = 0;
    View row3;

    String status;
    private  Handler mHandler;
    HorizontalListView listview;
    CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
    String DescriptionAPI;
    // ImageLoader2 imgLoader;
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
    ImageView img1;
    String URL, URL2;
    String SelectMenuAPI;
    static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String allergen2;
    private AQuery androidAQuery;
    String name;

    String description;
    String url1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_image);

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuname);
        txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

        androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);

        listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

        cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(fifthscreen.this);

        new getDataTask().execute();

    }

    void clearData() {
        Category_ID.clear();
        Category_name.clear();
        Category_image.clear();

    }

    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        getDataTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (IOConnect == 0) {
                txt1.setText(name);
                txt3.setText(description);
                androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);
                listview.setAdapter(cla);

            }
        }
    }

    public void parseJSONData() {

        SelectMenuAPI = "http://198.57.208.46/~school/api/index/getDishDiscription?dish_name=testingdish";

        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams
            .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    atomInputStream), 8192);

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                str += line;
            }

            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

            status = json2.getString("status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {

                    name = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");

                    description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                            "description");

                    url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");

                }

                JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

                final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

                for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

                    String s = String.valueOf(j + 1);

                    row3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
                    ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))
                    .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
                    ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))
                    .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            table.removeAllViews();
                            table.addView(row3);
                        }
                    });

                }

                JSONArray school4 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_allergen");
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < school4.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school4.getJSONObject(i);

                    Category_ID.add((long) i);
                    Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                    Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));

                }

                final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);

                JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

                for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

                    row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
                    ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5
                            .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                    .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "sub_ingredients"));

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            table3.removeAllViews();
                            table3.addView(row4);
                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            else {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);

                    Category_ID.add((long) i);
                    Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

                }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IOConnect = 1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but im updating my textview on loop see this line  JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

        for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

Comment: but how i wrute my textview on postexecute? my textview inside forloop se this line
 JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

        for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

            row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
            ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
            ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                    .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "sub_ingredients"));

Comment: @smartguy see my edit, I loaded your project and added `removeAll()`, now it works

Answer (score 0):

Remove parseJSONData() this method from doInbackground() because asynctask is not allowed UI update from doInBackground method. Put this method in onPostExecute() there it will work for sure. Because You can not update UI in doInBackground() method.

Comment: how do you run n/w operations on the ui thread? `HttpResponse response = client.execute(request)` which is in `parseJSONData()`

Comment: Just parse data there, it fine, but you cant set that data in any of UI, for that you must need to do code in onPostExecute or out of asynctask. make your asyncTask return type is string arraylist and return your parseJson data from there. Then display that data in onPostExecute. because right now you are using all the 3 params as a Void.

Comment: like, new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>(){
}

Comment: @patik you cannot run n/w realted operation on the ui thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html. the main thread is the ui thread. so if you put `parseJSONData()` in `onPostExecute` which has `HttpResponse response = client.execute(request)` you will get an excpetion. `onPostExecute`is invoked on the ui thread.

Comment: ur advidce not work parseJSONData() crash on postexewcute instead of background

Comment: you doing wrong, your code is wrong dear..advice is fine, read any document. Post your updated code and let me make it error free.

Answer (score 0):

Dont Update your View in your `doInBackground()`.

Declare your All layout, TextView Globally.

Create `ArrayList<String> myArraylist1,myArraylist2`,& Store your Values in it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

           myArraylist1.add(school5
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
          myArraylist2.school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "sub_ingredients"));
}
```

Add All the Values & View in your `onPostExecute()`.

```
textname.setText(myArraylist1.get(0));
```

Comment: but u write myArraylist1.get(0) number zero hard code in my code forloop is undifined int i = 0; i < school5.length();

Comment: its an example.. use this idea in your way..use for loop

Comment: r uthere?? please check my project file  https://www.zeta-uploader.com/685453428 and dowhat u say is only single activity

Comment: I dont repair the Application in free. I have suggest you a way. implement it.If u stuck then u can ask. I cant understand that are you trying to create listview View inside of that for loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change UI in this method you can simple call a method which contains UI changes on same activity & you can call that method in onPostExecute method.

You better to call  parseJSONData() in doInBackground() without UI changes.